# SSIS OLEDB COMMAND query issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to run this query in the SSIS OLEDB COMMAND but for some reason I get this error(see shot)

```
update district set district.districtname=? 
from district inner join city on district.id=city.districtid 
where city.fdocode=? and city.taxcode=?
```

[image]

Comment: What versions of SSIS and SQL Server are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
update d
set districtname = ? 
from district d inner join city c on d.id=c.districtid 
where c.fdocode=? and c.taxcode=?
```

Answer (score 0):

0x80004005 messages usually imply some kind of access violation.

Have you checked the identity that the command is running under can issue the command? This should be easy to check by running the SQL Profiler to confirm that the SQL Server gets the command.

To determine this look at

1. how the connection manager is connecting to the db. Is that correct?
2. how are you running the package - manually or via SQL server? If via Sql Server then does it work if you run it manually in Visual Studio
3. You need to learn how to debug SSIS - this looks like a good beginners tutorial.